# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' | `pip install pandas` & `poetry add pandas` fail

Tags: python, pandas, python-poetry, modulenotfounderror

I've been able to run and install `pandas` library before...

Included is IDLE traceback, at bottom of post.

I'm starting to believe there is more of an underlying serious issue with my setup. Really not sure what the problem is.

```
$ pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Terminal:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ pip install --upgrade pip

Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.7 MB 722 kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-21.3.1

me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3; platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64" and python_version < "3.10" in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.14.0)

me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ poetry add pandas
Using version ^1.3.4 for pandas

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (649.1s)

  SolverProblemError

  The current project's Python requirement (>=3.8,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.6, <3.10, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.10,<4.0
    - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.6, <3.10, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.10,<4.0
  
      Because no versions of tensorflow match >2.5.0,<2.5.1 || >2.5.1,<2.5.2 || >2.5.2,<2.6.0 || >2.6.0,<2.6.1 || >2.6.1,<2.6.2 || >2.6.2,<2.7.0 || >2.7.0,<3.0.0
   and tensorflow (2.5.1) depends on numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0), tensorflow (>2.5.0,<2.5.2 || >2.5.2,<2.6.0 || >2.6.0,<2.6.1 || >2.6.1,<2.6.2 || >2.6.2,<2.7.0 || >2.7.0,<3.0.0) requires numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0).
      And because tensorflow (2.5.2) depends on numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0), tensorflow (>2.5.0,<2.6.0 || >2.6.0,<2.6.1 || >2.6.1,<2.6.2 || >2.6.2,<2.7.0 || >2.7.0,<3.0.0) requires numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0).
      And because tensorflow (2.6.0) depends on numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0)
   and tensorflow (2.6.1) depends on numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0), tensorflow (>2.5.0,<2.6.2 || >2.6.2,<2.7.0 || >2.7.0,<3.0.0) requires numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0).
      And because tensorflow (2.6.2) depends on numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0)
   and tensorflow (2.5.0) depends on numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0), tensorflow (>=2.5.0,<2.7.0 || >2.7.0,<3.0.0) requires numpy (>=1.19.2,<1.20.0).
      Because no versions of pandas match >1.3.4,<2.0.0
   and pandas (1.3.4) depends on numpy (>=1.20.0), pandas (>=1.3.4,<2.0.0) requires numpy (>=1.20.0).
      Thus, pandas (>=1.3.4,<2.0.0) is incompatible with tensorflow (>=2.5.0,<2.7.0 || >2.7.0,<3.0.0).
  (1) So, because tensorflow (2.7.0) depends on tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (>=0.21.0), if pandas (>=1.3.4,<2.0.0) and tensorflow (>=2.5.0,<3.0.0) then tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (>=0.21.0).
  
      Because no versions of tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem match >0.21.0,<0.22.0 || >0.22.0
   and tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.21.0) requires Python >=3.6, <3.10, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem is forbidden.
      And because tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.22.0) requires Python >=3.6, <3.10, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem is forbidden.
      And because if pandas (>=1.3.4,<2.0.0) and tensorflow (>=2.5.0,<3.0.0) then tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (>=0.21.0) (1), pandas (>=1.3.4,<2.0.0) is incompatible with tensorflow (>=2.5.0,<3.0.0)
      So, because data-simulator depends on both tensorflow (^2.5.0) and pandas (^1.3.4), version solving failed.

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│ 
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties
    
    For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.8,<3.10"
    For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.8,<3.10"

    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies,
    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers

me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ poetry run python3 cli.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 5, in <module>
    from alien import *
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src/alien.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

---

**Suggested Solution:**

Uninstall, re-install, run again failed.

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ pip uninstall pandas
Found existing installation: pandas 1.3.4
Uninstalling pandas-1.3.4:
  Would remove:
    /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas-1.3.4.dist-info/*
    /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/*
Proceed (y/n)? Y
  Successfully uninstalled pandas-1.3.4
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.3.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3; platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64" and python_version < "3.10" in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.14.0)
Installing collected packages: pandas
poetry run python3 cli.py
Successfully installed pandas-1.3.4
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ poetry run python3 cli.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 5, in <module>
    from alien import *
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src/alien.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

**IDLE:**

```
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    ls
NameError: name 'ls' is not defined
>>> import pandas as pd

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 143
    from . import _distributor_init
UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

>>>
```

Uninstalling Numpy worked but for Setuptools failed

```
danielbellhv@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/dabell/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ pip uninstall -y numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.21.3
Uninstalling numpy-1.21.3:
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.21.3
danielbellhv@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/dabell/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ pip uninstall -y setuptools
Found existing installation: setuptools 45.2.0
Uninstalling setuptools-45.2.0:
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 791, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__/easy_install.cpython-38.pyc' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-cmpyrogm/easy_install.cpython-38.pyc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 97, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "/home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 671, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 384, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 282, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 307, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 812, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__/easy_install.cpython-38.pyc'
```

Changing Permissions of file `` failed:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__$ chmod 755 easy_install.cpython-38.pyc 
chmod: changing permissions of 'easy_install.cpython-38.pyc': Operation not permitted
```

---

Please let me know what else I can try or add to post

Comment: Do you use a virtual environment? If not, could you try using one?

Comment: I'm using a package dependency handler **Poetry**. So I'd like this to run on any machine in any environment. Or should I anyway? Just haven't needed to before.

Comment: What is your pip version? Have you checked this issue https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3894 ?

Comment: `pip 20.0.2`. I'll check that post out.

Comment: Try to upgrade your pip and try again

Comment: No luck ;( Appended to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Identification:**

I had tried many things: `pip install -y poetry` & `pip install -y poetry-core`.

However, I clearly still had some fragments of Poetry left on my system.

So, whenever I ran `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3`, it would never give a full installation feedback.

This is because: **`bin/lib/poetry/`** still existed.

Possibly due to trying miscellaneous/ informal pip commands to uninstall, instead of the recommended approach, as per [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/).

> If you see something like Poetry 0.12.0 then you are ready to use Poetry. If you decide Poetry isn’t your thing, you can completely remove it from your system by running the installer again with the --uninstall option or by setting the POETRY_UNINSTALL environment variable before executing the installer.

```
python get-poetry.py --uninstall
POETRY_UNINSTALL=1 python get-poetry.py
```

---

**Solution:**

`rm poetry/ -r`.

Then try installing again:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3
Retrieving Poetry metadata

This installer is deprecated. Poetry versions installed using this script will not be able to use 'self update' command to upgrade to 1.2.0a1 or later.
# Welcome to Poetry!

This will download and install the latest version of Poetry,
a dependency and package manager for Python.

It will add the `poetry` command to Poetry's bin directory, located at:

$HOME/.poetry/bin

This path will then be added to your `PATH` environment variable by
modifying the profile file located at:

$HOME/.profile

You can uninstall at any time by executing this script with the --uninstall option,
and these changes will be reverted.

Installing version: 1.1.11
  - Downloading poetry-1.1.11-linux.tar.gz (64.48MB)

Poetry (1.1.11) is installed now. Great!

To get started you need Poetry's bin directory ($HOME/.poetry/bin) in your `PATH`
environment variable. Next time you log in this will be done
automatically.

To configure your current shell run `source $HOME/.poetry/env`

me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator$ poetry install
bash: /home/me/.local/bin/poetry: No such file or directory
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator$ poetry run python3 cli.py
bash: /home/me/.local/bin/poetry: No such file or directory
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator$ source $HOME/.poetry/env
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator$ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 82 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

...
  • Installing numpy (1.19.5)
...
  • Installing pandas (1.3.1)
...
```

Comment: I feel like a true SO user now

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps...

Uninstall & re install pandas again

```
pip uninstall pandas
```

Know

```
pip install pandas
or
pip3 install pandas
```

Check if Pandas installed or not

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

Comment: Runtime doesn't reach `pd.__version__`.

Comment: Why you executing everything on terminal? Have you tried executing in *Idle?*  . Have u installed any Idle's on your pc/laptop?

Comment: It's my preferred approach, simply. I've not installed an Idle.

Comment: No No...First  debug in IDLE & then run on Terminal.....Terminal is bit messy.....When u debug on IDLE you can easily find where the problem is clearly....Always u must debug first on IDLE & then run of Terminal

Comment: It's take some time to you to get used with IDLE's but as a developer you must first develop/Debug on Idl'es & then run on terminal. Follow following YouTube video ......https://youtu.be/f0ZmRH63Rts

Comment: Ok, I've added IDLE traceback to post

Comment: Yes know check this site

https://exerror.com/importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-_multiarray_umath-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found/

Comment: Attempt to `pip uninstall -y setuptool` failed. In post